# What would be the pros and cons of the extensive use of NOT NULL values?

Tags: sql

What would be the pros and cons of the extensive use of NOT NULL values? And what would be a good method to amend the use of not nulls within an existing schema?

Comment: Declare columns that should never have `NULL` values as `NOT NULL`.  There are no "pros and cons".  It is just a question of how accurately you want to represent the data.

Comment: Amending is rdbms dependent. Look at documentation on how to use something like `alter table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pros:

1. Not Null fields don't require Null variable, so it saves bit of space if the column is lesser in length (e.g. 1 char) and you mostly will have values there.
2. While coding in application program, you don't need to worry about the null values and don't need to do extra coding for null indicator (e.g. in COBOL).
3. The fields are forced to have a value, e.g. a 'Y'/'N' situation. If you want to force people to answer a Yes/No question, use Not Null.
4. While write queries you don't need to write something like 'Where col <> 'Y' and col IS NOT NULL'. So, query size is reduced.
5. While joining tables, you don't need to worry if the Joined column will have a Null.
6. It may also help in aggregate functions especially if you want to have a default value like '1' in some int column.
7. Also helps in ensuring relational integrity as Null values are Not checked for RI.

Cons:

1. Counter to point 1 above, If you have a large field and you use Not Null then you may be wasting space if you don't want to have that field populated most of the times.
2. While inserting rows, you'll need to make sure to pass a value for a Not Null column.
3. You'll need to decide beforehand what values (or default) you want for that column.
4. If you use Null, then you can intelligently make use of Null values without much coding e.g. suppose you have a frequency of 'M'onthly and 'Y'early and you want to introduce a new frequency of 'S'emi-monthly, then if NULLs are allowed then you don't need to populate that column with a 'S'. You'll know if it is Null then that means Semi-monthly. You can get away with introducing a new frequency. You can handle that Null in your program.
   You can't do this if column is Not Null.
5. If your application requirements change, then you need to change that Not Null value whereas a Null can remain a Null.

Comment: This has helped me completely, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Cheers!